# Is there any method to find the next possible element following the list's pattern?

Tags: python, list, probability

I want a method to get the next possible element as a continuation of the list following the pattern on the list.

Say, there is a list ls,
`ls = [1,2,2,3,2,2,1,2,2,3]`

And I want to get the next possible element of the list.. In this case, "2".

Comment: Nope.  What you're talking about requires artificial intelligence.  You could do it with a neural network, but that requires a library.

Comment: There is any number of ways to continue that sequence - what is the way you're after? Why is "2" the answer? Here's a few other possibilities https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C2%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C3&language=english

Comment: After continuing the pattern 2 is the outcome

Comment: Because... the pattern is 2s interrupted by 1 and 3 alternating every three positions, starting at the first position? My point is that that's *a* continuation, but the link I shared shows several others. What continuation should be preferred and why?

Comment: Maybe 2 is the outcome.  Maybe not.  There is no definitive answer.  There is only a probability.  That's why AI is involved.

Comment: It's silly to suggest "AI is required" - that's like saying "you need the answer". "AI" is likely just referring to a specific statistical approach to finding patterns, there are many different approaches, most of which have nothing to do with AI. However, the problem is poorly defined, so the answer is anyone's best guess. What "AI" is, isn't even clearly defined.

Comment: The next number is clearly 42. Always.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the length of the shortest cycle while iterating over the list.

```py
cycle = 1
for i, x in enumerate(ls):
    if x != ls[i % cycle]:
        cycle = i + 1
print(ls[len(ls) % cycle]) # 2
```

Comment: This works for the sample, but it doesn't work for `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]` or even `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion that "AI is required" is of course silly. But your problem statement is unclear. The series you provide as an example can be followed by a 2, but other solutions are possible as well, here's a few examples on the [OEIS website](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C2%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C3&language=english).

However, assuming that you're looking for the trivial extended arithmetic progression (repeating a fixed number of simple arithmetic steps indefinitely), this is a solution:

```
def find_pattern(xs):
    if len(xs) < 2:
        return [0]
    n = 1
    while n < len(xs):
        pattern = list(map(lambda x: x[1] - x[0], zip(xs[:n], xs[1:n + 1])))
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(xs, xs[1:])):
            if y - x != pattern[i % n]:
                n = i + 1
                break
        else:
            return pattern

sample = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3]
pattern = find_pattern(sample)
print(pattern)
```

And with that sample pattern, you could extend the series:

```
def extend_pattern(xs, pattern, n):
    x = xs[0]
    for i in range(n):
        yield x
        if i < len(xs) and xs[i] != x:
            raise ValueError(f'The series {xs} does not match the pattern {pattern} at index {i}.')
        x = x + pattern[i % len(pattern)]


print(list(extend_pattern(sample, pattern, 15)))
```

When combined, the output:

```
[1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2]
```

However, as an example that this gets horribly wrong:

```
sample = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
pattern = find_pattern(sample)
print(pattern)
print(list(extend_pattern(sample, pattern, 15)))
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 20, 22, 24, 28, 30, 34, 36]
```

To a person, it's fairly obvious that `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]` is a list of primes, but that's not what the function finds of course.